# I cannot get to the correct @Path

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

Using JAX-RS, I have the following 3 `@Path`s.

```
@Path(JobRest.PATH)
@Api(value = JobRest.PATH, description = "REST APIs for Jobs")
public interface JobRest {
    public static final String PATH = "/job";

    @GET
    @Path("/last")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Job retrieveLastJob(...);

    @GET
    @Path("/{jobId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Job retrieveJob(...., @PathParam("jobId") String jobId, );

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JobList retrieveAllJobs(....);
}
```

- `/job` correctly calls `retrieveAllJobs()`
- `/job/1236` correctly calls `retrieveJob(..., "1236", ...)`.

I expected that `/job/last` would call `retrieveLastJob(...)`, since it matches, but it calls `retrieveJob(..., "last", ...)` instead.

How do I change the notation so that `/job/last` will call `retrieveLastJob(...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Remove the `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` on the `retrieveJob` method. For one, it does not accept a body, so it does not consume anything. Secondly it conflicts with the expected behavior.

---

I've tested with both Jersey and RESTeasy and it seems to be a difference in implementation. Jersey works fine with your code, while RESTeasy always hits the `retrieveJob` method, as you are experiencing.

Here's my take. If you look at the [JAX-RS spec; 3.7.2 Request Matching](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html), there's a semi-cryptic algorithm for matching resources, that goes something like this.

1. Get all matching resource class (by path), put them into a set.
2. Get all matching resource methods (by path), put them into a set.
3. Sort the methods by best matching path (most literal characters go first).
4. Sort by media type (with consumes and produces).

From my perspective, in this particular case, after step 3, the `retrieveLastJob` should automatically win, as it has the most literal characters. The producing media types are the same, and the consumes media type should not even matter, since it is a GET request with no Content-Type to do any matching.

My guess it RESTeasy still uses the annotation to sort even though it should not even be taken into consideration in this case. So it would appear that the method with the annotation is given more precedence, as it *appears* to be more specific, by way of just having an annotation, while the other does not. But that (step 4) level of specificity really shouldn't matter in this case.

I don't know if it's a bug against the spec. It's not too clear on how it should be handled, but I personally think the Jersey behavior is the correct behavior, for the simple fact that this level of specificity should not matter in this particular case. In any case, it is not correct to have the `@Consumes` annotation anyway for a GET request with no body.

Comment: I took out the @Consumes annotation and that fixed the problem!